# Ejs Profile card formatting

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

I'm trying to fix the formatting on this project.

I'd like to have "for each" card created from data entry(server), to have them fall in rows. This ensures I have three cards per row. But my present code keeps formatting wrongly by having just one profile card per row.
WHich happens to be centered weirdly.

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<div class="row">
<div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">
  <%  items.forEach(function(items){ %>


  <img alt="John" style="width:100%" src="data:image/<%=items.img.contentType%>;base64,
                     <%=items.img.data.toString('base64')%>"> 
  <h6><%=items.name%></h6>
  <h6><%=items.dob%></h6>
    <h6><%=items.breed%></h6>
       <h6><%=items.details%></h6>

  <p><button>Contact</button></p>

        <% }) %>


  </div>
</div>



  <%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest the `.card` element inside your loop

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<div class="row">
  <% items.forEach(function(items){ %>
    <div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">
  
      <img alt="John" style="width:100%" src="data:image/<%=items.img.contentType%>;base64,
                           <%=items.img.data.toString('base64')%>">
      <h6><%=items.name%></h6>
      <h6><%=items.dob%></h6>
      <h6><%=items.breed%></h6>
      <h6><%=items.details%></h6>
  
      <p><button>Contact</button></p>
  
    </div>
  <% }) %>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

Comment: Tried that. They are stacking on eachother. and For each new item, its width reduces whilst still stacking.  Heres my CSS                                                                                    .card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

Comment: Did you also make sure the `div.card`'s closing tag is inside the loop? If they are getting skinnier as you go that would indicate each new one is inside the previous one.